# How to init and access JSF2 session beans?

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

Let's say I have 2 managed beans:
Query and Login with session scope.

I can see that setQuery is invoked, but the parameter is null and therfore my method check() fails.
How to init the Bean "Query" since query is not a simple value but an object?

This is my Bean "Login" (not using annotations):

```
public class login {
  private Query query;

  public void setQuery(Query q) {
    query = q;
  }

  public Query getQuery() {
    return query;
  }

  public String check() {
    ... do s.th. with query
  }
```

And faces-config.xml:

```
...
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>query</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>Query</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>login</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>login</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>query</property-name>
    <property-class>Query</property-class>
    <value>#{query}</value> 
  </managed-property> 
</managed-bean>
...
```

Comment: if you are using JSF 2 you should use annotations to declare managed beans inteads of declare them in faces-config. Use @ManagedBean(name = "login") @SessionScoped. How are you setting Query?

Comment: Damian, thank you for helping. I had a lot of problems using Java 5, which makes a lot of troubles. Since almost nobody uses Java 5 any more we shoud delete this question, because it is misleading. All my problems disappeared using Java 6.